# Function not returning default value C++

Tags: c++

This code will return the values of 1 or 0 when those returns are called, but if it falls to the default return value of 2, it doesn't return it. I'm sure it's something small I'm missing, but I can't figure it out.

```
int comp(string a, string b){
    char x;
    char y;
    int i = 1;
    int len;
    len = a.length();
    if(b.length() < (unsigned)len){
        len = b.length();
    }
    len++;
    while(i!=len){
        x = a.at(i);
        y = b.at(i);
        if(getNum(x) < getNum(y)){
            return 1;
        }
        else if (getNum(x) > getNum(y)){
            return 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 2;   
}
```

Comment: The `len` variable should be declared as `size_t` or `unsigned int`.  I've never encountered a string with a negative length.

Comment: Whatever this function is supposed to be doing, it's doing it wrong. Indexes start at 0, not 1.

Comment: Please edit your post with the *definition* of `getNum`.

Comment: What does it return if it doesn't return 2?

Comment: 'getNum' just returns the number of a character's location in the alphabet. ex: a - 0, b - 1, z - 25

Comment: I `cout` the results of the return immediately and it doesn't print anything.

Comment: @Upgrayded _"and it doesn't print anything."_ Forgot flushing? Add `<< std::flush;` to your `std::cout` statemen`

Comment: @Upgrayded what's the test case that produces that result? (i.e. what are a and b when you expect 2)

Comment: The same to strings are the test case. So I am using "alpha" and "alpha".

Comment: `len` is returned by `a.length()`, and the call to `length()` does not return an int, so comparing `i` which is int against `len` would yield unequal and the loop keeps incrementing `i`, which will eventually go beyond the int value of `len`, that is why your code does not return 2.

Comment: @Polb It does seem to be a loop issue. But if I `cout` inside the loop it only prints the correct number of times which is why I didn't catch it. I'm not sure why the loop would only loop a certain number of times but not break out of it at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
i=0;
```

Delete below code on top of the while loop

```
len++;
```

You are actually getting an exception there. Because on the last run, you are having indexoutofbound exception.

If your string is "hello" the length is 5 which mean your index is 0,1,2,3,4.

```
h e l l o
0 1 2 3 4
```

With your len++ it raised the length to 6. And on the last round of while(5< 6) you are tring to access index of 5 which does not exist

Hope it helps

Comment: Omg thank you. I knew it was something stupid.